# Does Shakespeare steer the reader's sympathy towards Venus or towards Adonis?

Tags: poetry, william-shakespeare, venus-and-adonis

In the narrative poem [*Venus and Adonis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_and_Adonis_(Shakespeare_poem)), Shakespeare reuses a story from Ovid's *Metamorphoses* (which he often used as a source of inspiration), but gives it an original spin: Venus's desire is presented as predatory, and Adonis tries to reject her and get away. It is also striking that Venus get many more lines than Adonis. Is Shakespeare trying to steer the reader's sympathy towards Venus giving more attention to her point of view, or are we still supposed to sympathise with Adonis?

---

For an online version of the poem, see e.g. the [Shakespeare Folger Library](https://www.folger.edu/venus-and-adonis).